# How to add an SQL expression to the entity query? (D8)

Tags: 8, database

Assume we have an entity query like the following:

```
$query = \Drupal::service('entity_type.manager')->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->getQuery();
$tids = $query->condition('vid', 'tags')->execute();
```

and we need to add some SQL expression and condition based on it, like the following:

```
Replace(name, ' ', '-') = 'some-tag'
```

How to do that?

The `Drupal\Core\Entity\Query\Sql\Query` class does not have methods for doing so (unlike `Drupal\Core\Database\Query\Select`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using query **tags** and **metadata** the underlying `Select` query can be altered easily.

```
$query = \Drupal::service('entity_type.manager')->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->getQuery();

// Add tag and any metadata to the entity query.
$query->addTag('my_category')
  ->addMetaData('my_category', $dynamic_category_name);

$tids = $query->condition('vid', 'tags')->execute();
```

And then in `my_module.module` file:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_query_TAG_alter() for my_category tag.
 */
function my_module_query_my_category_alter(\Drupal\Core\Database\Query\AlterableInterface $query) {
  $expression = "Replace(taxonomy_term_field_data.name, ' ', '-')";
  $args = [
    ':dynamic_category_name' => $query->getMetaData('my_category'),
  ];

  $query->addExpression($expression);
  $query->where($expression . ' = :dynamic_category_name', $args);
}
```

Comment: This is a really nice solution example. I want to try something similar, but with `->condition('BINARY field_on_my_taxonomy_term', $values, 'IN')` to do a binary-collated comparison. And while I did find a way to get it working, I had to do some odd things, since it's a field in a different table. I had to add a condition like `->condition('field_on_my_taxonomy_term', 'ALWAYS_TRUE', '<>')`, so that the needed JOINs are added. *continued in next comment...*

Comment: Example of what I had to use: `->addTag('where')->condition('field_on_my_taxonomy_term', '( always_true )', '<>')->addMetaData('where', ['snippet' => 'BINARY field_on_my_taxonomy_term_value IN (:array[])', 'args' => [':array[]' => $values]])`. I'm not sure if there's a better way.